# Host Private Pip Repository

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to host my private python package in aws ec2. I use flask app for this. I placed my package inside a folder in the root of the flask app. In the route function, after successful aunthentication, i am trying to send the file using send_file. when i try the url with my browser, the response is the attachment of my package. But when i try to install using pip

pip install mypackage --extra-index-url=https://myurl

I am getting the following error :
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement packagename (from versions: none)
No matching distribution found

Pip expects the response from the url to be in 'text/html' format. Initially, i was getting an error that  the response is of type octset, but i changed the mimetype. eventhough somehow i am unable to get the package downloaded.

also, i tried with PEP503 directory structure,

- simple
  -packagename

  - index.html
    -index.html

In this case, what should my url return?. render the index.html? or link to the file?

Directory structure in Ubuntu AMI:
directory1

- package-name

  - package.name-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
- app.py
- templates
- static

Answer (score 0):

If your packages are at `/simple/` then you need to include this in your `extra-index-url` e.g. the command to install from [piwheels](https://www.piwheels.org) (a third-party public repo) is:

```
pip install numpy --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple
```

The `/` root of your website is not used by pip, only the simple index is. The `/` index (and anything other than `/simple/`) can simply be used to provide human-readable information for users, like a homepage and possibly even `/project/<package>/` project pages (like https://www.piwheels.org/project/numpy/) but that's probably not necessary if it's a private index.

You can run an index without server-side code, simply generate `/simple/index.html` and `/simple/<package>/index.html` for each package, store your wheel files in `/simple/<package>/<filename>.whl`:

```
www
└── simple
    ├── index.html
    ├── numpy
    │   ├── index.html
    │   └── numpy-1.19.4-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
    └── scipy
        ├── index.html
        └── scipy-1.5.3-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
```

And (optionally) extra pages and project pages outside of `/simple/`:

```
www
├── about.html
├── index.html
├── project
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── numpy
│   │   └── index.html
│   └── scipy
│       └── index.html
└── simple
    ├── index.html
    ├── numpy
    │   ├── index.html
    │   └── numpy-1.19.4-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
    └── scipy
        ├── index.html
        └── scipy-1.5.3-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
```

But if you stick with Flask, that's fine (as long as Flask stays up), provided you route everything in the first example.

Refer to the HTML files in PyPI and piwheels for reference, e.g. view source of https://www.piwheels.org/simple/numpy/index.html and (DOWNLOAD FILE - DO NOT OPEN IN BROWSER - IT'S HUGE)... `piwheels.org/simple/index.html`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Big question i have is, what should be response of the url function(https://mydomain/simple/). should i return render_template('index.html')

Comment: Yes. wget the final URL in my response and return an HTML response in that format.